# Update socket.connected Socket.IO immediately when network down

Tags: javascript, networking, socket.io

Currently, I want to check status of socket when network is down with connected property. But i have an issue when unplug network cable, the connected status still true for 20 seconds or more. How can i get the status immediately ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the `timeout` option, which by default is set to 20.000 MS (20 seconds). You can find a lot of information here: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#

I would disrecommend making it absolutely instant though. Most if not all networks have *some* instabilities, which are accounted for by the timeout delay. It's there for a good reason. Maybe just make it a bit shorter?